# Fit Iframe content with the size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a Facebook application to add tabs for pages, the user give me the link of the hosted content shown in the page tab.

this is an example of a tab added by [my application](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Floupie/216620338351068?sk=app_183495898374566).

I want the full URL content to be shown in the page tab frame, Facebook tab properties :
Max Width : 520px
Max Heigth : 800px

Is there any method to reduce the percent of the width + height of the iframe, if the content is don't fit with the size ?

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly; you might have success reading over the Facebook's JavaScript SDK, particularly [`FB.Canvas.setSize()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) and [`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/).